# Python scipy.io.wavefile doesn't find read() function

Tags: python, scipy, wav, wave

The Python IDE doesn't import `read()` function from `scipy.io.wavefile`.

I'm using Python 3 and Eclipse

```py
import scipy.io.wavfile
Fs,data=scipy.io.wavfile.read(FileName)
```

and getting the following error ( Eclipse Message )

> Undefined variable from import: read

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *`Undefined variable from import: read`*  Is that really the exact error that you get?  Is that in an exception that occurs when you run the code?  Or is it a message from Eclipse?

Comment: Hi, It's a message from Eclipse. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Pycharm IDE and this code worked fine.Maybe there is issue with path variable.The best possible solution I would suggest is;create a new virtual environment,install the scipy module in that virtual environment and try again.The following is the code to create a virtual environment:

```
>python3 -m venv <name_of_virtualenv>
```

To activate the given environment of linux or mac;browse to the bin of the virtual environment and use the following command:

```
>source activate
```

And then you can use the regular pip command to install scipy.

I hope my answer helps you